# importing aop context gives Cglib error

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

Error Stack trace.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:477)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1655)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:162)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:446)
    at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:206)
    ... 30 more
```

aop config file .

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

<bean id="methodBeforeAdviceImpl"
    class="com.x.y.common.aop.advice.MethodBeforeAdviceImpl" />
<bean id="methodBeforeAfterLogAdvice"
    class="com.x.y.common.aop.advice.MethodBeforeAfterLogAdvice" />
<bean id="exceptionLoggingAdvice"
    class="com.x.y.common.aop.advice.ExceptionLoggingAdvice" />
<!-- <aop:aspectj-autoproxy /> -->
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="methodLoggingPointcut"
        expression="execution(* com.samsung.alterego..*.*(..))" />


    <aop:advisor advice-ref="methodBeforeAfterLogAdvice"
        pointcut-ref="methodLoggingPointcut" id="methodLoggingInterceptorAdvisor" />

    <aop:advisor advice-ref="exceptionLoggingAdvice"
        pointcut-ref="methodLoggingPointcut" id="exceptionLoggingAdviceInterceptorAdvisor" />

    <!-- <aop:advisor advice-ref="methodBeforeAdviceImpl" pointcut-ref="methodLoggingPointcut" 
        id="methodBeforeAdviceImplAdvisor" /> -->
</aop:config>
```

"

This issues i can see only when i integrate with mogo db.  It is unable to create proxy for the repository [@repository ]and services [@services]

Comment: Can you show the code your are using?

Comment: The problem is that you are using 2 different AOP approaches which lead to creating a proxy of a proxy. Your `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` interferes with `<aop:config />`. It is better to stick to a single approach to prevent these kind of proxy errors.

Comment: what code you want repository /aop code ?